# URL link wont work in backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have a project done in backbone and I have one problem regarding basic links on the page , when I click on the link url has been copied to existing url and it wont lead to defined address , for example

in template I have link : `<a href="http://www.google.com" class="google_link">google.com</a>`

and in backbone I have this event : '`click .google_link' : 'google_link'`

and function :

```
google_link: function(e) {

                $el = $(e.currentTarget);
                var link = $el.attr('href');
                Backbone.history.navigate(link, {trigger: true});

            },
```

and when I click on link i get address like this

```
http:// localhost:8888/backboneApp/#http://google.com
```

I know this is not right way but can anyone tell me how to handle static links to do normal stuff ?

**EDIT** without events its doing the same thing , just paste url to adress and nothing happens

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to handle the external URLs. It should automatically be take care.
Just try removing the events, it should work fine.

Comment: when I remove the events its doing the same thing , thats why i try to fix it with events

Comment: I tried your code in my application. It works fine. Not sure whether any CSS is causing any problem